# How to decode QR-code image in laravel5 or php?

Tags: php, laravel-5, qr-code

I am using 'robbiepaul/zbar-qrdecoder' package to decode QR code image in laravel5.

I have put "robbiep/zbar-qrdecoder": "~1.3" in require of composer.json and 'RobbieP\ZbarQrdecoder\ZbarQrdecoderServiceProvider' in providers array of app.php but while updating composer it is showing the following error:

```
[BadMethodCallException]
Call to undefined method [package]
Script php artisan clear-compiled handling the post-update-cmd event returned with an error

[RuntimeException]
  Error Output:
update [--prefer-source] [--prefer-dist] [--dry-run] [--dev] [--no-dev] [--lock]
 [--no-plugins] [--no-cust`enter code here`om-installers] [--no-autoloader] [--no-scripts] [--no-
progress] [--with-dependencies] [-v|vv|vvv|--verbose] [-o|--optimize-autoloader]
 [--ignore-platform-reqs] [--prefer-stable] [--prefer-lowest] [packages1] ... [p
ackagesN]
```

Is any other package available to decode QR code image in laravel5 or php?

Comment: Is `QRDecode 1.3` available for the version of Laravel you using ?

Comment: yes..it is supporting. pls refer this link https://github.com/robbiepaul/zbar-qrdecoder

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you install [ImageMagick](https://www.imagemagick.org/script/download.php).

Open up terminal and follow:

```
sudo apt-get install zbar-tools
composer require robbiep/zbar-qrdecoder    
php artisan vendor:publish
```

Hope this solves your error!